# How to hide a tag and its content inside another tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

In my web application I have a select menu generated by querying MySQL where I want to show some vendor's information. Inside that I also need to have the id of the vendor (so that if the user clicks on row than street address is showed) but I don't want the id to be showed to the user. This is what I have tried server-side with php:

```
$value = $value."<p style='display:none;'>".$single["vendor_id"]."</p>";
```

but it does not work. The generated HTML for that row is:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-6" tabindex="-1">
    PANNA - LE MUCCHE DI GUGLIELMO - (LATTICINI) - LE MUCCHE 
    <p style='display:none;>1</p> 
    (33.543 Km)
</li>
```

which shows this
[image]

This is what I get from php:

```
$ris2[] = array(
            "value" => $value,
            "id" => $id,
            "venditore_id" => $single['venditore_id']
);
```

and this is the Ajax call client-side:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://lainz.softwebsrl.it/ajax/autocompletecibo",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                type : 'post',
                data:
                {
                    valore: request.term+","+localLocation,
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
```

And this is `autocompletecibo.phtml` to which the Ajax is directed:

```
<?php 
  $data = $_GET;
  $data1 = $_POST;
  json_encode($data);
?>
```

I really don't know where to retrieve that associative array php...I just know that everything is inside `value` in the array will be showed as row in `<li>` elements.

Comment: Is that a list item in the pic?

Comment: if you need to store your id, place it inside the `id` attribute of your `li`

Comment: @ThoVo I don't have control in php in <li> tag and content. It is generated later and not by me...

Comment: then you should discuss with the one who generated the `li` tag about this problem. Is he/she really put the `id` inside the `p` and ask you to hide it?

Comment: no, it was one of my ideas...I don't know where to store that id and anyway I don't have control on <li> elements...

Comment: it is not semantic and never be a good way to display some content with hidden value but if you really want to go with this idea, try with `visibility:hidden` in an external css, you don't need to place them inline

Comment: ok, let's say I will not do this for the reason you have said. How/where could I store that value? Again, the HTML is generated by zend framework so I can't directly control <li>

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the generated HTML you can alter the content by jQuery before binding any listeners or plugins to it:

```
$('li.ui-menu-item').each(function(i, elm) {
    elm = $(elm);
    var p = elm.find('p');
    elm.data('id', p.text());
    p.remove();
});
```

Then all ids are stored as data attributes inside each `<li>` element.

Comment: Eventually, create a jsfiddle or plnkr, otherwise I can't test it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you because I know very little of jQuery...what are elm and i?

Comment: I am afraid we're not understanding each other...see my update question if you want